# Why was my question closed and where can I ask it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[Is dnyuz.com a Russian or Eastern European hacksite masquerading as a news site?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227021/is-dnyuz-com-a-russian-or-eastern-european-hacksite-masquerading-as-a-news-site?noredirect=1#comment464298_227021)

It was quickly closed with the blurb "Unfortunately, we can't analyse the site for you or do a reputational deep dive."

Meanwhile, in the "Related Questions" sidebar, there's a question "Anyone heard of this site and is it safe?" which got answered with details, which obviously means my question wasn't off-topic or prohibited.

I checked the rules for what is on-topic and off-topic. I don't see a specific rule that my question broke to get closed. All I'm seeing right now is a double standard.

If this stack exchange isn't the place for my question, then where can I post it? Is anyone going to help me? At least can you please give me pointers on where to ask it or where to hire a professional computer/network security contractor to look into this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been addressed in comments. It is also based on false assumptions.

Comment: "which obviously means my question wasn't off-topic or prohibited" -that's not obvious at all - did you read the question.

Comment: The assumptions are not false. At least allow someone else to weigh in instead of reflexively obstructing everything I do. Where can I post this then??? I'm basically screaming for help and all I see is a single person with a vendetta against me. Where's the arbitration?

Comment: I provided all the tools you need in the comments section. Please calm down.

Comment: Where do I post this question then? Is there another Stack Exchange or Q&A site where it would be on-topic?

Comment: There is no other StackExchange site where this would fit. You want access to people who would spend time digging around for you. Reddit? Or, you could use the tools I mentioned, of use a sandbox with JS enabled so you could safely dig around the site.

Comment: Reddit is unusable. Their web UI is a mess and their censorship is really bad. There's a reason why I don't use them.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reasons that has already been given in comments explain why the question was closed. There is nothing in the question to indicate that the site would be a "hacksite" (whatever that means) other than the that it is unclear who operates it. If we allowed questions of that kind about individual sites we could have loads of them, and they would all quickly be out of dates since ownership and status of sites can change rapidly.

As for the other question, it is different. There are some concrete technical details that can be discussed in a more general way relevant to more than the individual site. But frankly it is not a great question and I would not have protested if it had been closed as well.

So while I understand the motivation for your question, I don't think this is the right place to ask it. And as far as I know, it doesn't fit in anywhere else on the SE network either. Can't really say where you would get a good answer on this. I would suggest Reddit, but you already ruled that out.